# event.target.name is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to use e.target.name in react to set the state as I have done before, however e.target.name seems to be undefined for some reason and I can't figure out why, if any one has a suggestion it will be welcome.
thanks!

```
<li
    onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter.bind(this)}
    name="HOME"
    id="some id"
    style={main.element}
>
    HOME
</li>
```

my event handler has only a debugger for me to play with

```
handleMouseEnter(e) {
    debugger
}
```

and when i try to get the value of the name property i get undefined

```
e.target
//<li name=​"HOME" id=​"some id" style=​"padding:​ 10px;​">​HOME​</li>​
e.target.name
//undefined
e.target.id
//"some id"
```

Comment: `e.target.getAttribute('name')`

Comment: If you `console.log(e)` in your handler, what do you get out?

Comment: The values like `id` are properties. There are some rules for different types of html elements the properties are different. For an `<input>` element, `id`,`name`,`type` etc are valid. For `<li>` tag the property `name` is not a valid one, hence `e.target.name` is undefined. You'll need to access it just like any other custom attributes.

Comment: Thanks! this really clarify it!

Answer (score 36):

`name` is an attribute and needs function `getAttribute(...)` to be fetched. As @Ele has pointed out, the suggested solution would be

```
var name = e.target.getAttribute('name'); //'HOME'
```

Answer (score 12):

- Form fields are the elements who must use the attribute `name`.
- The JS engine will automatically set that attribute within the form elements (`input`, `select`, etc).

```js
document.querySelector('li').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('Directly: ' + e.target.name);// prints null
  console.log('Using getAttribute: ' + e.target.getAttribute('name')); // prints ele
});

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('Directly: ' + e.target.name);
  console.log('Using getAttribute: ' + e.target.getAttribute('name')); // prints ele
});
```

```html
<input name="ele" placeholder="Click me!">
<li name="ele">Click me!</li>
```

---