# React - Unable to uncheck the "check" checkbox

Tags: reactjs

I am blocked with unchecking the checkbox. there are two check fields sms and email i am able to check and uncheck checkbox for sms but for email field uncheck is not working
Here is my code,

```
    const Notifications = ({
  editAlertState,
  setEditAlertState,
  handleNotifyByEmailSMS,
  handleNotifyByChange,
  name,
  userEmail,
  handleToggle,
  phoneNumber,
  placeId,
  errors,
  register,
}) => {
  const places = useSelector((state) => state.entities.places.data);
  const generateNotificationList = (editAlertState, name, places, placeId) => {
    let place = null;
    if (placeId) {
      place = places.filter((place) => place.id === placeId)[0];
    } else {
      place = places[0];
    }
    let options = editAlertState.editPlace
      ? [
          `When ${name} is located near ${place.name}`,
          `When ${name} is not located near ${place.name}`,
          "Always",
        ]
      : ["Always"];

    return options.map((e) => {
      return {
        key: e,
        value: e,
      };
    });
  };


    <div className={style.notify_wrapper}>
                <TmoH4 className={style.subheading}>How to notify me</TmoH4>
                <div className={style.checkbox}>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={editAlertState.SMS}
                    id="text"
                    value="SMS"
                    name="notifyBy"
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      handleNotifyByEmailSMS(e, editAlertState, setEditAlertState)
                    }
                  />
                  <label htmlFor="text">
                    Text message {StringUtilities.formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)}
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className={style.checkbox}>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={editAlertState.email}
                    id="email"
                    value="EMAIL"
                    name="notifyBy"
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      handleNotifyByEmailSMS(e, editAlertState, setEditAlertState)
                    }
                  />
                  <label htmlFor="email">Email {userEmail}</label>
                </div>
```

i am not able to uncheck email checkbox. Can anyone please tell what exactly i am missing in this

Comment: Where `editAlertState.SMS` is defined?

Comment: Can you add the code of `handleNotifyByEmailSMS` method ? It would be easier to see what is happening when you update the state

Comment: @gladix - added

Comment: @yahyaparvar - editAlertState.SMS this is no defined anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending the props back to the parent component complicates things too much, the parent already has the props.

But to solve the problem with the current design, I think that in your parent component, `handleNotifyByEmailSMS` does not differentiate which box the user has clicked, you could use `e.target.getAttribute('name')` in your case to make this distinction and set `editAlertState.SMS` or `editAlertState.email` accordingly

See: [Pass props to parent component in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639534/pass-props-to-parent-component-in-react-js)
and [event.target.name is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991117/event-target-name-is-undefined/48991233)