# event.target.name is undefined after submit

Tags: reactjs

I want to get value = 100 from event.target.value, but result in null instead. but event.target has the form that I submit, I guess I just dont know the right way to access the data.

Similar question but solution didn't work for me [event.target.name is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991117/event-target-name-is-undefined)

code for the form

```
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Control
                  name={item.ID}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state[item.ID] || ""}
                />
                 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </Form>
```

handleSubmit code

```
handleSubmit= (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
let item = {
  ID: event.target.name,
  Price: event.target.value,
};
console.log(event.target)
console.log(event.target.getAttribute('value'))
console.log(event.target.name)
console.log(event.target.value)
// putSubcategories(item, this.submitCallback);
```

}

event.target gives back

```
<form class><input name="1" class="form-control" value="100"><button type="submit">Submit</button></form>
```

event.target.getAttribute('value') = null

event.target.name = null

event.target.value = null

Answer (score 1):

submit Event is on the form. So you get the form element which does not have the properties you look for.

```
let targetInput = event.target.querySelector('input');
console.log(targetInput )
console.log(targetInput.getAttribute('value'))
console.log(targetInput.name)
console.log(targetInput.value)
```