# I cant the value of the element name - e.target.name returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

In onClick event i capture the event(e) in a function
and trying to get the name of the element that was clicked

```
const ClickEvent = (e) => {
console.log(e.target.name) -> undefined
}

<svg>
<text onClick={ClickEvent} name="line1">
 hello world
</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Are you using React here?

Comment: yes, is that make any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM attributes are not always available as direct named properties of the element. I would advise you to use [the `getAttribute()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to fetch the values of the attributes you want.

```
console.log(e.target.getAttribute('name'))
```

Comment: Do you know if there is any documentation to support this– "DOM attributes are not always available as direct named properties of the element."? I've seen the same thing but haven't been able to find anything official on it.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to use the getAttributes method, as the DOM can be a little finicky sometimes.

```
const ClickEvent = (e) => {
   console.log(e.target.getAttribute('name'))
}
```

Similar question for more reference: [event.target.name is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991117/event-target-name-is-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `e.target.name` method, try `e.target` and check the console to find the method you want.

I guess you mean `e.target.localName`?